# Giving conditions inside rails filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a method in a controller as follows:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
 caches_action :listing

  def listing
   #..........#
  end

end
```

And I can access `@page` variable from another controller by inheriting the app controller:

```
class ApplicationController
  before_action :get_page

  def get_page
    @page = #page
  end
end
```

I am having hard time figuring out is how can I do

`caches_action` only `if @page?` inside filter in **pages controller**

Answer (score 2):

you can write it like this

`caches_action :listing, if: -> { @page.present? }`

or

`caches_action :listing, unless: -> { @page.blank? }`

Answer (score 0):

you can have conditional based approach, as per the [documentation](http://%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.1/classes/ActionController/Caching/Actions.html)

```
          caches_action :index, :if => proc do
            !request.format.json?  # cache if is not a JSON request
          end

          caches_action :show, :cache_path => { :project => 1 },
            :expires_in => 1.hour

          caches_action :feed, :cache_path => proc do
            if params[:user_id]
              user_list_url(params[:user_id, params[:id])
            else
              list_url(params[:id])
            end
          end
```

or a simple approach suggested already,

> caches_action :listing, if: -> { @page.present? }

Use it as per the requirement.